# Math Random Coin Toss

Tags: c#, random

I wrote a function A, and inside this function there is below code piece.

```
rnd.Next(1,3);
```

If I run my A function hundred times, and print out the results, results are not realistic  for example it is always win or always lose. So the random function is problematic. I need a realistic real random function.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the code (where you run `A` a hundred times and collect results)?

Comment: Please add some piece of code to let us help you

Comment: Let me guess, you're seeding `rnd` inside the function, every time?

Comment: [Have a read of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/838807)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you've done a typical error with `Random`, you're *re-creating* it each time i.e:

```
  Random rnd = new Random();
  int toss = rnd.Next(1,3);
```

If you do this, rnd could well start *each time* from the *same seed* and that's why the result is *badly skewed*. The solution can be something like that:

```
   // Let it be thread-safe
   private static ThreadLocal<Random> s_Gen = new ThreadLocal<Random>(
    () => new Random());

   // Thread-safe non-skewed generator
   public static Random Generator {
     get {
       return s_Gen.Value;
     }
   }

   ...

   int toss = Generator.Next(1,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
int i = rnd.Next(int.MaxValue) % 2;
```

Then have a check whether `i = 0` or `i = 1`.

**EDIT** Yes, as [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040523/math-random-coin-toss/21040741#21040741) mentioned do not instantiate a new `Random` object each time.